# Problems uploading package to Launchpad due to "checksum mismatch" error

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad, upload, dput

I'm having a lot of problems uploading my showdown project to a PPA.

I've setup correctly PGP keys and my public SSH key to Launchpad. I've packaged with debuild my C++ project, producing a source package lintian gave me only those two warnings that I think are ok for the showdown rules:

```sh
W: massren source: native-package-with-dash-version
W: massren source: binary-nmu-debian-revision-in-source 1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2
```

Producing a binary package works too, and the package installs without problem on my Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise" machine. I only have a few more lintian warnings about the fact I'm installing files into `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/<packagename>`.

I'm uploading with the command:

```sh
dput ppa:gabrielegreco/massren massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2_source.changes
```

When I upload with dput I have no errors, signatures seems ok, and public key seems to be accepted, too (since the upload goes on without asking for passwords…). This is the output from `dput`:

```
$ dput ppa:gabrielegreco/massren massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2_source.changes

  Checking signature on .changes
  gpg: Signature made Mon 02 Jul 2012 10:00:38 AM CEST using RSA key ID 49982576
  gpg: Good signature from "Gabriele Greco <gabrielegreco@gmail.com>"
  Good signature on /home/gabry/no-backup/massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2_source.changes.
  Checking signature on .dsc
  gpg: Signature made Mon 02 Jul 2012 10:00:33 AM CEST using RSA key ID 49982576
  gpg: Good signature from "Gabriele Greco <gabrielegreco@gmail.com>"
  Good signature on /home/gabry/no-backup/massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2.dsc.
  Uploading to ppa (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
  Uploading massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2.dsc: done.
  Uploading massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2.tar.gz: done.    
  Uploading massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa2_source.changes: done.
  Successfully uploaded packages.
```

At the moment I'm not receiving responses from Launchpad site, but the upload does not show in the PPA page.

Previous attempts gave me response emails with different kind of errors:

```sh
File massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa1.tar.gz mentioned in the changes has a checksum
  mismatch. 1503fa155226cbc4aba2f8ba9aa11a75 != 294a5e0caf3fe95b0b007a10766e9672
File massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa1.tar.gz mentioned in the changes has a checksum
  mismatch. 1503fa155226cbc4aba2f8ba9aa11a75 != 294a5e0caf3fe95b0b007a10766e9672
```

Or more cryptically:

```
GPG verification of
  /srv/launchpad.net/ppa-queue/incoming/upload-ftp-20120629-163320-001135/~gabrielegreco/massren/ubuntu/massren_1.0-0extras12.04.1~ppa1.dsc
  failed: Verification failed 3 times:
    ["(7, 58, u'No data')", "(7, 58, u'No data')", "(7, 58, u'No data')"]

Further error processing not possible because of a critical previous error.
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem? I'm new to Ubuntu packaging, so I may miss some step… Is there is an alternative to `dput` (a/k/a manual upload)?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem was in the untangle firewall that is between me and launchpad. I've uploaded the files by hand at home and sent them through FTP to launchpad.

I used the command line "ftp" client since I cannot use "dput" on OSX and ncftp did not worked (maybe because it didn't set the correct email as password of the anonymous user)?

Anyway this is the sequence to do to upload manually:

- Connect with FTP to ppa.launchpad.net
- Use anonymous as user
- Use the mail address you used to register to launchpad as password
- change directory to ~yourlaunchpadusername/yourppa/ubuntu
- upload the files packagename_version.dsc, packagename_version.tar.gz, packagename_version_source.changes
- exit FTP and wait for email confirmation.

If your build doesn't complete correctly (in my case the problem was an unmet dependency) you have to upload the files with a different version or you'll get an error (I changed ~ppa2 to ~ppa3 in the end).

Answer (score 1):

Open `~/.dput.cf` in a text editor and add this text:

```
[your-ppa]
fqdn = ppa.launchpad.net
method = ftp
incoming = ~<your_launchpad_id>/<ppa_name>/ubuntu/
login = your_launchpad_id

allow_unsigned_uploads = 0
```

Save the file, quit the text editor, and run:

```
dput your-ppa *_source.changes
```